# Program halts until the user enters text and presses Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a button to change the text of some widget. The user will press the `change_text` Button, which launches the main function. The program will then wait until the user has given text to an `Entry`, then pressed an `Enter` Button. The `target_widget` will change its text and the program will continue.

Here's some code similar to what I'm working on:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.grid()

CIN = StringVar(root)
COUT = StringVar(root)

entry = Entry(root, textvariable = CIN)
prompt = Label(root, textvariable = COUT)
target_widget = Label(root, text = '')
enter_button = Button(root, command = proceed)
change_text_button = Button(root, command = change_text)

def change_text():
    COUT.set("Enter text to entry")
    # Wait until user presses enter_button
    input_text = CIN.get()
    target_widget['text'] = input_text

def proceed():
    # continue program
    pass 

change_text_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
enter_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
target_widget(row=0, column=2)
prompt.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I have the program waiting until the user has pressed `Enter`?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is that `change_text` and `proceed` functions are defined after your widgets, so when the interpreter is parsing, it does not know where the heck these functions are. Just put them before the creation of your widgets.

The second problem you have is that you are tying to grid `target_widget` but you are actually trying to call an inexistent function with the same name:

```
target_widget(row=0, column=2)
```

Change it to:

```
target_widget.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

You can also use some text for the Button that calls the callback. Change this:

```
change_text_button = Button(root, command = change_text)
```

To this:

```
change_text_button = Button(root, text='Change Text Button', command = change_text)
```

Which is more suggestive and understandable.